AD&D Which guns can thieves use?
Anachronistic cross over games. Stuff like Muskets, Arquebus, Blunderbuss, Dragoons, and Flintlocks on the High Seas, or even Wild West Six shooters and Kentucky Long Rifles from the Colonial period.
How do I figure out what weapons are allowable for thieves in 1st or 2nd edition Advanced Dungeons and Dragons when they weren't even in the Core Rules when they first made their list?

Thieves can use both guns, or they are disarmed.

Theives can use all firearms
At least, according to 1st edition rules. Looking at the two 'official' sources I know of:
1st Edition DMG (P113-114). There is a lengthy discussion in the DMG on how to convert characters between Boot Hill and Gamma World. Use of both Black powder firearms and high tech artifacts (ex: Laser guns) are mentioned. While it is stated as being optional to allow such devices into your campaign, nothing is said to explicitly disallow any class from using them. In fact, clerics and magic-users are granted a slight bonus when tring to figure out their use.
Module S3 This module features a number of high tech weapons and artifacts, and no class is explicitly banned from using them. A character needs to figure out their operation via some random rolls, but that is the only restriction on their use.
In re-reading these sources, Gary's only real concern here seemed to be overall game balance, and not class balance.

We ended up using Masque of Red Death and Dragons #60 and #70 for references. We had been using Gamma World for a While. Masque had a thief XP table Class based on Merchants and they had no restrictions, but the question came from the fact that all weapons were replaced by guns, therefore, which guns would a thief use, not 'can a thief use guns'. Reality is most thieves (and assassins) have used guns since the 1500s. According to the Rules as Written, I'm the DM, and we use common sense, historical reference, and logic. Rule restrictions aren't automatically "all this" or "not all this".

Great citation, @Tristian, thanks for suggesting it.

In second edition, there's a Kit for that
As Nobody says in his answer, in the 2e core rules, thieves have a restricted list of weapons with which they can become proficient, and none of the gunpowder weapons you suggest are on that list.
However, if you look beyond the core rules to the Complete Thief's Handbook (1989), there are a number of Kits you can take, DM-permitting, that will allow you to access firearm proficiency.
The Adventurer, Assassin, and Bounty Hunter Kits outright say that you are allowed proficiency in "any weapon".
The Thug Kit permits you to take 'Non-Thief' weapon proficiencies, but at a cost of one extra slot.
Finally, the Buccaneer Kit permits 'classic buccaneer weapons'.  While these are not defined, I imagine that would include a flintlock pistol.
In 2.5, it just costs more
Later, the Player's Option Series (sometimes called edition 2.5) overhauled the weapon proficiency system such that any weapon was permitted to any class - depending on the number of proficiency slots or character points they spent on it.  So, if the DM permitted proficiency in firearms, a thief could have that - but they would expect to pay more for it than a fighter.  These rules can be found in PO: Combat and Tactics and PO: Skills and Powers (both 1995).
In first edition, gun use is a function of setting, not class
The advice given in first edition is simply to not permit firearms to be used in your fantasy setting (DMG 113):

Transferal Of Fire Arms To The AD&D Campaign: Unless you desire to have gunpowder muddying the waters of your fantasy world, it is strongly urged that BOOT HILL firearms be confined to specific areas, and when gunpowder is brought into the fantasy world it becomes inert junk -- ergo, no clever alchemist can ever duplicate it.  Likewise, dynamite and similar explosives become inert.

Thus, no first edition characters are going to have initial proficiency in firearms, regardless of their class, because those firearms don't exist in their world.  On the other hand, such characters could travel to a world where such weapons exist (DMG 112); for example, you may:

opt to have a space/time warp throw...the adventurers from your fantasy milieu [into] a Wild West setting.

Once there, however, an AD&D PC would not gain proficiency in firearm use, that is, they would neither treat firearms as a permitted selection on which to spend their weapon proficiencies nor have a non-proficiency penalty applied when using them.  Rather, they would simply adopt the independent BOOT HILL firearm use rules.  They would start with a "Gun Accuracy" statistic of 01, and then "each 6 rounds fired add +1 until a maximum of 25".  Note that neither the rate of their progression nor the maximum value would be dependent on their class.  Other statistics are class-dependent, though: a ported PC's "Bravery" would depend on their wisdom score but also their character class.
In summary, no 1e PC would begin with proficiency in firearms, but if for some reason they found themselves in an area where firearms worked, any PC could gain the local equivalent of proficiency regardless of class.

I generally agree with the Buccaneer kit theory. I do not agree with the logic of unknown unknowns. A ban on a weapon is a list of known weapons not permissible. Arabian adventures introduced Jambiya and they became wizard weapons.  "Sorcerers are limited much like standard wizards; they must choose from among the dagger, staff, knife, jambiya, dart, and sling."
When new weapons are introduced, they need to be chosen as restricted or not restricted. Automatically restricting them is illogical. AD&D uses Logic, not RAW.

@Tristian If you are saying that when weapons are introduced in the rules, they should come with a statement of which classes are permitted to use them - but AFAICT they didn't.  Would you prefer an answer that says simply "you can't figure that out b/c gunpowder weapon proficiencies aren't described?"  About as close as 2e comes, I think, is the description of the Dwarven Sharpshooter Kit, which kinda says 'treat the arquebus as a crossbow for proficiency stuff'.  I can add that to my answer if you would like.

@Tristian As far as the "logic" of the default assumption being not permitting a proficiency, I think the idea is that firearms are optional, and not necessarily part of any particular campaign world.  If a DM permits firearms, the onus is on them to decide how and why they are part of the world.  A given player cannot just expect that their PC is suddenly proficient with a weapon just because the DM introduced it.  Even for fighter class PC's who are technically proficient with all weapons, "all" here means something like 'weapons they can reasonably have trained with in their backstory'.

Man, your inclusion of the Adventurer kit in 'any weapons' category was a eye opener O.O I always saw the kit just as the general kit describing the class. About 2.5, I imagine you suggests to allow a wizard to pay 6 CPs for proficiency with a firearm, resuming: firearms are normally allowed to warriors and bards and are on the restriction list of the others.

None, by the core rules
This is on page 38, PH, in the Thief class description:

Thieves have a limited selection of weapons.
Most of their time is spent practicing
thieving skills. The allowed weapons are
club, dagger, dart, hand crossbow, knife,
lasso, short bow, sling, broad sword, long
sword, short sword, and staff

Guns are not on the list, so thieves are not competent using them. Given how noisy firearms are, they'd seem an unusual choice of weapon for a thief who often must rely on stealth. Talk to your DM if you envision a character concept for your thief using a firearm, and see if they make an exception for you, or have defined this differently in case firearms are common in their world.

P.S. Firearms are not entirely foreign to the AD&D 2e core rules. The DMG discusses arquebuses for an expanded "Renaissance" technology level equipment list, and even mentions that Smoke Powder (a magical substance that is similar, though not identical to gunpoweder) can be used for arquebus charges. However, it does not provide a modern firearms table, as 5e does, but leaves that to the DM.

By RAW there's no such thing as a weapons restriction for a weapon introduced after the lists are published. I thought every DM knew that? Weapons restrictions are thematic, not publication canon.

@Tristan You should maybe read this answer on what RAW means. It means there needs to be a rule written that allows you to do something, otherwise it is not rules-as-written.

Arguably, @Tristian, there are few weapons restrictions at all.  Rather, there are weapon allowances.  Note the wording of the PH quotation in this answer.  It says "Thieves may use [...]".  That's what enables them to use those particular weapons, RAW.  Furthermore, it does not make sense (RAI) to say that any weapon not on the standard weapon lists is allowed to all classes.  If there is a weapon so different from all the standard ones that we can't consider it equivalent to one of them, then why would it make sense for any class to provide for competency with it?

(Though, RAW, some classes might nevertheless allow it.)

@Tristan, compare this for example with the Warrior superclass that includes Fighters and Paladins. This states "Warriors are allowed to use any weapon.", so that would include any additional, as yet unpublished weapons. But if you are convinced of your view, the best thing would be to post it as an answer, and you can see how that goes in voting.

When a new rule is introduced to any roleplaying game, it is the duty of the referee to adjudicate any decisions of balance, culture, and theme as follows narrative and common sense. A fighter is not a magical being who is downloaded with all weapons knowledge, they have to pay proficiency slots for everything including their first sword or axe. Weapons restrictions in AD&D are thematic, religious, or reflections of practicality, born out of Gygaxian need for balance. When guns come into the world, everyone, from a preacher to a warlord uses them, but criminals use them the most.
